# How can I show that x-3y=k is transferred to (-2k, k) in a non-regular linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Show that in the linear transformation
> $$f:\begin{bmatrix}x'\\y'\end{bmatrix}\mapsto\begin{bmatrix}-2&6\\1&-3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix},$$
> the line $x - 3y = k$ is transferred to the point $(-2k, k)$.

I have written my solution as follows. However, I think that this doesn't do what I need to prove. Could you give me your advice on how I need to show the solution to this problem?
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x' \\
y'
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 6 \\
1 & -3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
-2k\\
k
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
10k\\
-5k
\end{bmatrix}\\
x' = 10k, y' = -5k\\
From \ k=\frac{y'}{-5}, x' = -2y'
$$
Therefore, the line $x - 3y = k$ is transferred to the point $(-2k, k)$  (Since $y$ is -2 times x).

Comment: Why didn't you solve for $x$ and plug that in? If $x-3y=k$ then $x=3k+y$. Now calculate the image $f\binom x y$. You were calculating *the image* of the point $(-2k,k)$ but the task was to prove that *all* the points on that line get mapped to *the same point*, namely $(-2k,k)$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks for the reply. The advice you gave helped me to get the solution. / Should I self-answer the solution?

Comment: Good! Yes, I recommend a self-answer. You may get more feedback on your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I took [the advice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4195586/how-can-i-show-that-x-3y-k-is-transferred-to-2k-k-in-a-non-regular-linear-tr#comment8702736_4195586) given by @JyrkiLahtonen and solved the task as follows. If there are any deficiencies or improvements, I would appreciate your comments.

---

From the equation of the line, $x=3k+y, y=\frac{x-k}{3}$. Since we show that all points on the line move to $(-2k, k)$, we have
$$\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
x' \\
y'
\end{bmatrix}
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 6 \\
1 & -3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
3k+y\\
\frac{x-k}{3}
\end{bmatrix}\\
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
-2(3k+y) + 2(x-k)\\
4k+y-x
\end{bmatrix}\\
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
-8k+2x-2y\\
4k+y-x
\end{bmatrix}\\
x' &= -8k+2x-2y\\
&=-8k+2(3k+y)-2y\\&=-2k\\
y' &= 4k+y-x\\&=4k+y-(3k+y)\\&=k
\end{align}
$$

Comment: What happened to the equation from the original question? It said $x - 3 y = k$, but in some places, you substitute $x = 3 k + y$. That’s a different equation.